# Hide a tab on createBottomTabNavigator (navigationOptions: {tabBarVisible: false}) not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to hide the tab `E` in the below code. I'm using `createBottomTabNavigator` to create tabs in react native. I've tried the below code. `tabBarVisible` is not working though my logic is returning `false` for tab `E`. please help. Thanks!

```
var RouteConfigs = {
    A: {screen: A},
    B: {screen: B},
    C: {screen: C},
    D: {screen: D},
    E: {screen: E},

}
var BottomTabNavigatorConfig = {
    navigationOptions: ({navigation})=>{
       is_visible = navigation.state.routeName != 'E'
       return {tabBarVisible: is_visible}
    }
}
var ListTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    RouteConfigs, BottomTabNavigatorConfig
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this approach? This should help for nested navigators:

```
const getCurrentRouteName = (navigationState) => {
  if (!navigationState) {
    return null;
  }
  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
  if (route.routes) {
    return getCurrentRouteName(route);
  }

  return route.routeName;
};

const isTabBarVisible = (navigationState) => {
  return getCurrentRouteName(navigationState) !== 'E'
}
```

Comment: `createBottomTabNavigator ` is not considering the `tabBarVisible=false` for specific screen. I don't need the logic to get the boolean value. Please review the question. Thanks!